# Angle between vectors after rotating one of them

Tags: geometry, vectors, rotations

I have a unit vector $\hat{a}$ and a unit vector $\hat{k}=\{\sin\theta\cos\phi,\sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos\theta\}$. Now I can rotate $\hat{k}$ such that it aligns with the z-axis, i.e. $\hat{k} \rightarrow \hat{k}'=\{0,0,1\}$. Is there a way to relate the dot product $\hat{k}.\hat{a}$ and $\hat{k}'.\hat{a}$ given the two angles $\theta,\phi$ involved? I can find the Euler angles for the rotation but not sure how to proceed from there.

A similar question was explored before: [Find the angle between two vectors after rotating it.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/669948). But I was wondering if I can parametrize the relation in terms of just the angles involved in the rotation.

Any help would be appreciated. TIA!

Comment: What do you mean by $\hat{k}.\hat{a}$? Is this a mathematical relation?

Comment: I think it means dot product

Comment: Sorry, yeah, I meant the dot product

Comment: $\hat{k}'\cdot \hat{a}$ depends only on angle $\theta_a$ for $\hat{a}$ but $\hat{k}\cdot\hat{a}$ depends on both $\theta_a$ and $\phi_a$. So generally answer is No.

Comment: $\hat{k}'\cdot \hat{a}$ depends only on angle $\theta_a$ for $\hat{a}$ but $\hat{k}\cdot\hat{a}$ depends on both $\theta_a$ and $\phi_a$. So generally answer is No.